# How do I make changes to a Django Model after it has been deployed to a webserver?

Tags: mysql, django, model, synchronization

In development, whenever I make changes to the underlying model in my Django application, I'm used to:

1. Stopping the development server
2. In MySql, dropping the existing database
3. running $>python manage.py syncdb
4. Restarting the development server by running $>python manage.py runserver

Once deployed using WSGI & Apache, however, I don't have the development server running.  As such, I don't know how to stop the server, and just running:

> $>python manage.py syncdb

didn't appear to update the underlying MySql database that instantiates the model.  So, short of tearing down the entire instance, how do I update my database?

Note: I implemented this *before* I learned about db migrations using "south" so I'm looking at raw Django, I suspect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django doesn't have a migration framework built-in (yet!), so there's no such thing as "raw django for migrations".

Consequently, you either do that manually (using SQL to alter the table), or you use south.

Now, my recommendation would be to use [`south`](http://south.aeracode.org/).

Comment: By manually, do you mean ALTERing the TABLE in Mysql? if so, don't i still need to somehow stop and restart the service?

Comment: @AffableGeek Yes, that's what I mean, yes. For an answer to your second question, read the ["Storage, Performance, and Concurrency considerations" of this page from the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html). Also, do note that `south` will actually issue `ALTER TABLE`s to your database.

Comment: @AffableGeek You can add south after the fact. You'll be glad you did.

Comment: That's the plan, after the research - but I also had an immediate deadline I had to hit.  So, I did the immediate ALTER TABLE, and I'm learning South today.